# How to Disable text box when is empty in Angular2/4?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

[image]

Here I have some text box, Item id,item name,packing type and enter the add button  these data s save to DB.but here these data s are empty when i click the add button it will be Save to DB with null data s i want to avoid the null data s and disable the button if there is no data in the text boxes.

This is my html file

```
    <form #newStockRequestForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(newStockRequestForm.value);">          
         <section class="CommonWhiteBg">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Item Code</label>
                            <div *ngIf="selectedStock">                           
                                <input [(ngModel)]="selectedStock.ItemCode" id="ItemCode" placeholder="name" class="form-control" disabled name="ItemCode" #ItemCode="ngModel" ngModel>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Item Description</label>
                            <div *ngIf="selectedStock">                        
                                <input [(ngModel)]="selectedStock.ItemDescription" id="ItemDescription" placeholder="name" class="form-control" disabled name="ItemDescription" #ItemDescription="ngModel" ngModel>                           
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
.......................etc.......................
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right" style="margin-bottom:20px;">

                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success DefaultBtnStyle" value="Add Item" (click)="addItems(newStockRequestForm.value);newStockRequestForm.reset()" />
</div>
.............
```

Comment: I hope you can use angular's inbuilt form state (valid/invalid) to disable / enable the button, Make sure by default your input values are empty [Angular Doc on this](https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit)

Answer (score 2):

In your button add this

```
<input type="button" [disabled]="selectedStock.ItemCode === null || selectedStock.ItemCode === null" class="btn btn-success DefaultBtnStyle" value="Add Item" (click)="addItems(newStockRequestForm.value);newStockRequestForm.reset()" />
```

[stackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ue4vy4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: add other attributes as you want with ' || '

Comment: but one problem the add button will be disabled  all timecould not add item if the items are present in the textbox

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input 
     [(ngModel)]="selectedStock.ItemCode"
     id="ItemCode"
     placeholder="name"
     class="form-control"
     [attr.disabled]="!(selectedStock.ItemCode)"
     name="ItemCode"
     #ItemCode="ngModel"
     ngModel>
```

**[attr.disabled]="!(selectedStock.ItemCode)"**

Comment: an empty string is `false`

Comment: or you can `!selectedStock.ItemCode`

Comment: same problem reflect

Comment: By default, you can set empty value to each properties of ngModel object. Instead of null, you will receive empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Use newStockRequestForm.invalid/newStockRequestForm.valid after applying required validators to the inputboxes to conditionally enable or disable button.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#template-variable-references

I would like to add bit more for understanding purpose :

#newStockRequestForm = ngForm will bring the reference to the instance of the NgForm class to the template ref var (#newStockRequestForm). Using dot operator you can access its properties. eg: newStockRequestForm.invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in your component and call this function in the view to check the null value, as below

```js
isThereNullValue(){
// here you check the null values ​​for required fields
// return a boolean => true if there was a property with a null value
}

<input type="button" [disabled]="isThereNullValue()" class="btn btn-success DefaultBtnStyle" value="Add Item" (click)="addItems(newStockRequestForm.value);newStockRequestForm.reset()" />
```